# Enthought Canopy fails to start

Tags: windows, enthought, canopy

I have just installed Enthought Canopy on my Windows 7 32-bit (I have russian version of Windows). But when I tried to start it, I got a bug reporter dialog window saying "... we ran into a problem setting up your environment ...". I also tried reinstalling it as administrator to a custom folder (C:/Program Files/Enthought to be exact), but the problem persists. I tried to send bug report throught this dialog window, but it freezes and it seems it doesn't send anything. Has anyone encountered the same problem? What might be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anton, does your Windows user name (hence your home directory name) contain a non-ASCII character?

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23707691-Canopy-GUI-cannot-finish-setup-when-user-s-home-path-contains-non-ASCII-characters

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my case. I had this noted in my previous version of this question, but I thought that was not the case of the problem, when I tried to install Canopy as administrator to `Program Files` folder. Thanks, I'll wait for the fix then!

Comment: Understandable confusion. I updated the above article to briefly explain why installing to Program Files did not solve your problem.